# hazelcast migration from 3.x.x to 5.x.x using javaclient

Tags: java, migration, hazelcast

what is the alternate of the given below code while migrating it from 3.x.x to 5.x.x using java client

```
hz.getGroupConfig().setName(HZ_USER);
hz.getGroupConfig().setPassword(HZ_PASSWORD);
```

solution of the above question please some-one help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group config is replaced with the simple cluster name as shown here

https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3#replacing-group-by-simple-cluster-name-configuration

Basically, the group name is now the cluster name, and the deprecated password is removed altogether, as it was providing false sense of security.

Comment: So it means that from now onwards we cannot used hzlcastCofig.getGroupConfig().setPassword(HZ_PASSWORD); in 5.2.1

Comment: Yes, there is no replacement for password. If you are an enterprise user, you can take a look at the https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/security/native-client-security#authenticating-clients section for different ways of authenticating clients

Comment: can i ask you two more doubts related to hazelcast migration please

Comment: my first doubt is map.executeOnKey(imsi, new CollectionUnfragAddEntryProcessor( ));

Comment: alternate of this function in hazelcast config.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptPeriod()

Comment: The first one is the same in 5.x series, the same API exists.
For the second one, see the https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/clients/java#configuring-client-connection-retry section. You can configure the parameters there to achieve what you want

Comment: but sir i'm unable to change this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74906556/hazelcast-migration-from-3-x-x-to-5-x-x-issue-in-abstractentryprocessor-and-in-s
can you help me in that i'm just a fresher please

Comment: I can't add an answer or comment there as the question is closed, but you should now implement the EntryProcessor interface as shown here https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3#introducing-lambda-friendly-interfaces

I would recommend you to take a look at the all the changes in this page for migration from 3.x https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3

Comment: But sir there is three parameter in the EntryProcessor key,value i know and what i put in the 3 variable ?
And i forgot to thank you for the help sir

Comment: No problem at all, I am happy to help you. The third parameter represents the result type. So, when you execute map.executeOnKey(key, ep), your entry processor might return some value. In 3.x, the return value type was Object, and now in 5.x it is typed with the generic parameter R. So, you just need to change the R to the old return value type of your entry processor.

Comment: in the given link is valid for 3.x.x version
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/3.8.4/source-code/com/hazelcast/map/AbstractEntryProcessor.java

what can i do with the 5.x.x to implement 
public AbstractEntryProcessor(boolean applyOnBackup) {
        if (applyOnBackup) {
            entryBackupProcessor = new EntryBackupProcessorImpl();
        } else {
            entryBackupProcessor = null;
        }
    }

Comment: Like I said, the details are given in the link. I don't know what you are doing with the entry processor. If you want to run the entry processor on the backup entries as well, you can implement the getBackupProcessor according to your logic

Comment: can you please tell me what is the significance of UUID in the DistributedObjectEvent()
because in 3.x.x it is using 4 Arguments but in 5.x.x it is using 5 Arguments.
and if possible can you provide the link for that

Comment: Hi sir 
can you please take a look tell that whether it is correct or not ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914196/how-to-implement-public-abstractentryprocessorboolean-applyonbackup-in-5-x-x/74915927#74915927

Comment: That UUID specifies the source of the event, showing where it originated from.

Comment: The code shared in that answer is correct, you just need to extend that class in your entry processor and it is done. Regarding the EntryBackupProcessorImpl in your code, it does not exists anymore and you don't need it. Implementing getBackupProcessor as the answer shows is enough

Comment: while upgrading the hz_proxy_server to 5.2.1 i'm getting error

com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config":group}'. One of '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config":import, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config":config-replacers,.....

Comment: Since the group config is removed, it is removed from the XML config as well. The link I shared in the answer shows the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Hi sir,
can i used UUID.RandomId() in the 5th args if UUID doesn't have significance
DistributedObjectEvent newMapEvent = new DistributedObjectEvent(CRTD, 
"SERVICENAME", "NMAP", mkHzMp,<UUID>);
in the above method we are using 4 args in earlier version but now after upgrading to 5.x.x we are using 5 args 5th is uuid 
So, my question is that is there is any significance of UUID here
then what is it's significance

Comment: sir please help me in this ques
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979519/while-upgrading-the-hazelcast-3-12-x-to-5-x-x-then-what-is-the-alternate-of-the

Comment: Why are you creating those events? You will receive those events when you add distributed object listeners

Comment: so, what will i put in the 5 args of the New DistributedObjectEvent() it required there some uuid ?

Comment: Like I said, you shouldn't create this object, but If you are using it in your project and not considering it in your logic, you can put a random UUID there

Comment: Hi sir what is the alternate of the given below
<connection-attempt-limit>2</connection-attempt-limit>
because if i'm using the <connection-strategy >
then it is giving me this warning
/home/deepakmathur/HazelcastUpdate/hzpxy/sec-hz-proxy-server-main/src/test/java/com/evolvedintelligence/common/proxysrv/provLoader/HzcastProxyServerProvisioningLoaderImplTest.java

Comment: Please sir help in that question please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997724/while-upgrading-the-hazelcast-from-3-x-x-ro-5-x-x-im-facing-2-problem-i-e-gi