# what is the alternate of hz_Proxy_server_client.xml for 5.x.x series ? using javaclient

Tags: xml, hazelcast, java-client

this is the xml code for the hz_proxy_server.xml and
someone please write the alternate code for this one for the hazelcast 5.2.1

```
    <hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation=""
                      xmlns=""
                      xmlns:xsi="">
    
        <group>
            <name>HZuser</name>
            <password>passwd</password>
        </group>
    
        <network>
            <cluster-members>
                <address>199.23.32.23:1212</address>
            </cluster-members>
            <aws enabled="false"/>
            <connection-timeout>50000</connection-timeout>
            <connection-attempt-period>9000</connection-attempt-period>
            <connection-attempt-limit>4</connection-attempt-limit>
        </network>
    
        <properties>
            <property name="hz.loging.type">log4j</property>
            <property name="hz.cli.heartbeat.interval">2345</property>
            <property name="hz.cli.heartbeat.timeout">5654</property>
            <property name="hz.cli.invocation.timeout.seconds">35</property>
        </properties>
    </hazelcast-client>
```

Answer (score 2):

First please see related document for migrations, you can probably find answers for all your possible questions in there: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/migration-guides

And your new xml should be like this:

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation=""
              xmlns=""
              xmlns:xsi="">

<!--        <group>-->
<!--            <name>HZuser</name>-->
<!--            <password>passwd</password>-->
<!--        </group>-->
<cluster-name>HZuser</cluster-name>

<network>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>199.23.32.23:1212</address>
    </cluster-members>
    <aws enabled="false"/>
    <connection-timeout>50000</connection-timeout>
</network>

<connection-strategy async-start="false" reconnect-mode="ON">
    <connection-retry>
        <initial-backoff-millis>1000</initial-backoff-millis>
        <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
        <multiplier>2</multiplier>
        <!-- 4 * 9000-->
        <cluster-connect-timeout-millis>36000
        </cluster-connect-timeout-millis>
        <jitter>0.2</jitter>
    </connection-retry>
</connection-strategy>

<properties>
    <property name="hz.loging.type">log4j</property>
    <property name="hz.cli.heartbeat.interval">2345</property>
    <property name="hz.cli.heartbeat.timeout">5654</property>
    <property name="hz.cli.invocation.timeout.seconds">35</property>
</properties>
```

Comment: but brother after applying this i'm getting this
WARNING: hz.client_24 [dev] [4.2.6] Unable to get live cluster connection, retry in 2280 ms, attempt: 18, cluster connect timeout: INFINITE, max backoff: 30000 ms