# while upgrading the hazelcast 3.12.x to 5.x.x then what is the alternate of the given below code?

Tags: xml, hazelcast

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.8.xsd"
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<network>
<connection-attempt-period>1000</connection-attempt-period>
  <connection-attempt-limit>2</connection-attempt-limit>
</network>
```

what is the alternate of the above codes hazelcast-client-config-5.2.xsd

Answer (score 1):

Please see this page for details: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/clients/java#configuring-client-connection-retry

There is a `connection-strategy` element now. You can configure retries by using it.

```
<hazelcast-client>
...
<connection-strategy async-start="false" reconnect-mode="ON">
    <connection-retry>
        <initial-backoff-millis>1000</initial-backoff-millis>
        <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
        <multiplier>2</multiplier>
        <cluster-connect-timeout-millis>50000</cluster-connect-timeout-millis>
        <jitter>0.2</jitter>
    </connection-retry>
</connection-strategy>
...
```

Comment: but brother after applying this i'm getting this 
WARNING: hz.client_24 [dev] [4.2.6] Unable to get live cluster connection, retry in 2280 ms, attempt: 18, cluster connect timeout: INFINITE, max backoff: 30000 ms

Comment: so, can you please configure this code like after 2 attempts it will automatically shutdown

Comment: Hey @Deepak_M, please use https://hazelcastcommunity.slack.com/ for faster answers for this kind of questions.

Comment: brother please help me with my question i need help